# Curl inside "if" condition in shell script

Tags: bash, if-statement, curl

I referred to multiple articles to solve my problem but no luck. I'm trying curl inside `if`; as the value comparison is an arithmetic operation, I'm using the `>` operator with `((`.

However, the command is failing with error

> bash: ((: > 0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0")

Here is my command:

```
if (( $(curl --max-time 10 $serviceName) > 0)); then echo ERROR ; fi
```

What is wrong in the command?

Comment: What does the `curl` command  actually output? Seems like it's not producing *anything*, which means the command reduces to `if (( > 0 )); then`. You need something for the left-hand operand to `>`.

Comment: If you are trying to check whether `curl` failed (rather than its *output*), then `if ! curl ....; then echo ERROR: fi` is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks P.P

if ! curl --max-time 10 serviceName; then echo ERROR ; fi

worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
curl --max-time 10 "$someURL" || echo ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (curl --maxtime 10 $servicename); then
   blah;
else
   echo "Error";
fi;
```